# Login to vault failed with m-files, even though login to application succeeds

Tags: m-files-api

I am trying to hit the m-files document repository with the API and am having some problems.  I created a login on the server, and added that login to the vault - giving it "full control" permissions to the vault.  If I call from postman...

I first call `{url}/server/authentications`, with `X-Username` and `X-Password` set, and I get back an authentication.  I then use that to call `{url}/server/vaults`, and get back a list of vaults I've added this user to, with authentication tokens.

If I change anything in the user or password - I get a 403 error saying I'm not logged in, when going to /server/vaults - so I *know* that the URL, username, and password are correct.

But when I try to use that authorisation with X-Authentication - get anything vault related (e.g. `{url}/objects`) I get an error like this:

```json
{
    "Status": 403,
    "URL": "/objects",
    "Method": "GET",
    "Exception": {
        "Name": "UnauthorizedAccessException",
        "Message": "Login to vault failed"
    },
    "Stack": "Error reference ID: c3437561-d717-44f5-bba8-3468f0feb682",
    "Message": "Login to vault failed",
    "IsLoggedToVault": false,
    "IsLoggedToApplication": true,
    "ExceptionName": "UnauthorizedAccessException"
}
```

Which makes no sense to me because:

1. It says I'm logged into the application
2. It's the vault authorisation I got off the /server/vaults call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out the licence on the server had expired!    we'd renewed it, but nobody had ever installed the licence.   Suddenly everything started working.  Strange that some things work, and somethings just fail to login if you have an expired licence.